# SQL variable as database name, Incorrect syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query which I need to use variables as the database name. There are already number of questions about this. Although I followed them, I still have the `[S0001][102] Incorrect syntax near 'varchar'.` error. I guess that is sth related with text/characters in the query or sth else?

```
DECLARE @portalDB VARCHAR(60);
DECLARE @RemoteData_DB VARCHAR(60);
DECLARE @RemoteCenter VARCHAR(60);
DECLARE @RemoteCenterCMS VARCHAR(60);
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @portalDB = ' [portal_QA]';
SET @RemoteData_DB = ' [RemoteData_QA]';
SET @RemoteCenter = ' [RemoteCenter_QA]';
SET @RemoteCenterCMS = ' [RemoteData_CMS_QA]';

SET @SQL = 'SELECT customer.id AS cus_id
        ,machine.serialNumber as dl_id
        ,office.id AS location_id
        ,equipment_info.id AS asset_id
        ,CONVERT(varchar(20), office.id)'+'_'+'CONVERT(varchar(20), equipment_info.id) AS lid_id
        ,equipment_info.equipment_type AS et
        ,tool_type.name AS ty
        ,equipment_info.nickname AS ni
        ,equipment_info.project_id AS pi
        ,equipment_info.serial_number AS sn
        ,equipment_info.last_updated AS lu
        ,equipment_info.siebel_id AS sb
        ,component.duty_class as dc
        ,equipment_info.description as desc
        ,equipment_info.date_created as scad
        ,conn.connection_id as c
        ,component.capacity as cp
        ,component.main_component as im
        ,component.component_id as ci
        ,component.id as id
        ,component.serial_number as c_sn
        ,cms_crane.rowId as cms_RowId
        FROM' + @portalDB +'.[dbo].customer AS customer
        INNER JOIN' + @portalDB +'.[dbo].office AS office ON office.customer_id = customer.id
         INNER JOIN'+ @portalDB +'.[dbo].equipment_group AS equipment_group ON equipment_group.office_id = office.id
         INNER JOIN'+ @portalDB +'.[dbo].equipment_info AS equipment_info ON equipment_info.equipment_group_id = equipment_group.id
         INNER JOIN'+ @portalDB +'.[dbo].component AS component ON component.equipment_info_id = equipment_info.id
         INNER JOIN'+ @portalDB +'.[dbo].connection conn ON conn.id = component.connection_id
         INNER JOIN'+ @RemoteData_DB +'.[dbo].Machine machine on machine.serialNumber = conn.connection_id
         INNER JOIN'+ @RemoteCenter +'.[dbo].ToolType AS tool_type ON tool_type.id = equipment_info.tool_type_id
          LEFT JOIN'+ @RemoteCenterCMS +'.[dbo].Tool AS cms_crane ON equipment_info.project_id = cms_crane.craneId';

exec sp_executeSQL @SQL
-- tried with exec(@SQL) also
```

Comment: Simplify the query. Remove stuff not needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: What is `CONVERT(varchar(20), office.id)'+'_'+'CONVERT(varchar(20), equipment_info.id)` meant to be doing?

Comment: You should really be using `QUOTENAME` here on your dynamic object names. Otherwise this could very easily be open to Injection.

Comment: @Larnu I will consider your suggestion for `QUOTNAME`, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why you are not using `print @SQL` before `sp_executeSQL @SQL` to check how your query generated, the error is at concatenation :

It would be double quotes :

```
. . . 
,CONVERT(varchar(20), office.id)+''_''+CONVERT(varchar(20), equipment_info.id) AS lid_id
. . .
```

Do not use reserved keywords for instance `desc` would needs to quote `[desc]`.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly neater, harder to get wrong:

```
,CONCAT(office.id, ''_'', equipment_info.id) AS lid_id
```